# NsLocalization crash in ios9

Tags: simulator, xcode7

When I launch my app for simulator-iphone (ios 8 or ios 9), all works as expected.
When I launch it for simulator-ipad with ios 9, system freezes with LaunchImage displayed. (ios 8 is fine however). The last thing I see that has been called is applicationDidBecomeActive in AppDelegate.

The console is empty.

After waiting quite a long time (a few minutes) with CPU being at 99% app crashes with a very long system tack:

[image]

To note that it only crashes when user has Base language selected. With any other language there is no crash. I have checked all my localization files, but cant find any problem.

Comment: The stack trace is actually 30.000 entries deep, and all entries are identical

Comment: Looks like I am the only one having observed this abnormal behavior in xcode / ios. I have filed a bug report with apple